# How to create a new div row after every 3rd product in liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How do I wrap my products in a new `<div class="row"></div>` after every 3rd product? I have looked at using the `cycle` iteration tag but can't quite figure out how to implement properly in my code.

```
        {% for product in collection.products %}
            <!-- product -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 product">
                <a href="{{product.url}}" class="product-link"></a>
                <!-- / product-link -->
                <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '480x480' }}" alt="">
                <!-- / product-image -->

                <!-- product-details -->
                <div class="product-details">
                    <h3 class="product-title">{{product.title}}</h3>
                    <h6 class="product-price"> {{ product.price | money }}</h6>
                </div><!-- / product-details -->
            </div><!-- / product -->
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might use a modulo calculation applied on forloop.index then apply an if statement according to modulo result.

```
{% assign modulo = forloop.index | modulo : 3 %}
{% if modulo == 0 %}
<div class=«row»>
{% endif %}
```

https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/math-filters#modulo

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, if there are any better ways/suggestions I would be happy to hear them :)

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    {% cycle '<div class="row">','','' %}
            <!-- product -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 product">
                <a href="{{product.url}}" class="product-link"></a>
                <!-- / product-link -->
                <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '480x480' }}" alt="">
                <!-- / product-image -->

                <!-- product-details -->
                <div class="product-details">
                    <h3 class="product-title">{{product.title}}</h3>
                    <h6 class="product-price"> {{ product.price | money }}</h6>
                </div><!-- / product-details -->
            </div><!-- / product -->
     {% cycle '','','</div>' %} 
{% endfor %}
```